# How to update the index of files on the system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, filesystems

I have a full disk.

While trying to figure out what is taking the most space on my drive, I've been trying things out and I stumbled on this:

```
ghost@writtenby:~$ sudo du -s /
du: cannot access '/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/ghost_writtenby-adriengiboire-com.service': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/ghost_writtenby-adriengiboire-com.service': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/18669/task/18669/fd/4': No such file or directory

...
```

I wonder how it is possible to have such messages? I guess there is some general index of files on the system, right? How can I update it if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files had gone before du had the chance to explore them.  They existed when du explored the directory in which they existed.  No general index, each directory is in fact a separate file.  I think you can ignore those errors.  Eg.  "2>/dev/null".